# echo javascript in php not interpreted

Tags: javascript, php

I had to redirect the visitor to another page if something went wrong. Header location couldn't work because there is already some things displayed so I only have the choice to use javascript. Here is a piece of my PHP code :

```
add_action('frm_field_input_html', 'getDoctypes');
function getDoctypes($field, $echo = true){
    $url = 'http://ff/interface/iface.php';
    $html = '';
    if ($field['id'] == get_id_from_key_frm('doctype')){
        $data = array('action' => 'getDoctypes');
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'timeout' => 30,
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $return = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $doctypes = json_decode($return);
        if ($return === FALSE || isset($doctypes -> code)){
            $wpBaseUrl = site_url();
            echo "<script>window.location = '$wpBaseUrl/error-connection-interface/' </script>";
        }else{
            $html = ">";
            foreach ($doctypes as $code => $name){
                $html .= "<option value=\"$code\">$name</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    if ($echo)
        echo $html;
    return $html;
}
```

The problem is when $return === FALSE, instead of executing the script, it just display "window.location = 'http://my_ip/error-connection-interface/'" into the HTML

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding `type="text/javascript"` to that echoed `script` tag?

Comment: Still same problem :/

Comment: Open the developer tools and take a look at the generated html code, tag <script> may be filtered.